# Is API documentation and customer support good for SEO

Tags: seo

I work for a startup focusing on b2b in the finance area. Our products are not made to be known by casual customers. We have an API documentation, with some other stuff like support area to guide our customers through the using of our solutions.

I ran a check with sitechecker.pro to know more about our SEO ranking. Not too bad: 84/100. I do see some warning from our support pages like CSS is to heavy and we cannot adapt it as it's outsourced.

Personally I don't believe those articles (either support area or API doc) make customer come. Therefore, I'm wondering, is there any good reason to keep those articles around for SEO or would it be better to try bot not to crawl those?

Answer (score 1):

Speaking as someone who works with a lot of APIs, being able to search for and quickly find pages about those APIs based on perhaps odd things like object types (especially if you have custom exceptions), error codes or parameter names is invaluable.

One of the core considerations for me when evaluating a provider with an API is how easy is it for me to find documentation about it.

So does it help your SEO to have these pages available? Maybe.

Does it help your customers and users to have these pages available in search engines? Almost certainly.